# What is the recommend directory in which I can upload a new library?

Tags: directory

I am trying to install prebid.js to wordpress and I am still new to the whole structure of the wordpress installation. Is there any directory that I can safely upload to without breaking any dependencies or worrying about it being delete with an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a child theme folder named `yourTheme-child` in your theme's folder, and then upload your JavaScript files in that folder. (notice that `yourTheme` is the name of your theme's folder)

You might also want to create a folder named `js` inside that.

Take a look at : [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Child themes will not be deleted after updating your template/wordpress.

Then you can simply include your Js file in the header/footer this way:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="Full URL Goes Here"></script>`

or even better, enqueue your script it in the **functions.php** file using the below code:

```
function my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-js', 'Full URL Goes Here', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script' );
```